# Streaming data TO web server from Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming

It is possible to stream data **from** a Web Server using the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=VS.95).aspx) class in Windows Phone 7.

Unfortunately Microsoft removed the ability to stream data **to** a web server using this class.  The [AllowWriteStreamBuffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowwritestreambuffering(v=VS.95).aspx) property is not available on the phone.

Although you can write to the stream returned from [EndGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb(v=VS.95).aspx), the data only gets sent up to the server when you call [BeginGetResponse.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=VS.95).aspx)  Which means that if you have a massive quantity of data to send, it will all be buffered in memory.

If you control the server side, you can split the message into several requests, but this isn't always the case.

It struck me that perhaps I could embed a hidden [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.95).aspx) in my page, and then feed data to the browser using [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652559(v=vs.95).aspx), and have the WebBrowser's Javascript stream the data.

Before I go down this (rather messy) route, I wanted to know if anyone else has tried this, and if so, what issues did you face?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a world of pain....

Do you have any control over the protocol/software used on the server? If you do, then I think I'd change the protocol so you stream using a sequence of lots of HTTP requests rather than one big HTTP request.

Alternatively, if you can wait a couple of weeks, then something might be available in the new "Mango" tools release - it's definitely been suggested that Mango will "introduce support for TCP IP sockets" which hopefully will provide the sort of functionality you need.

Comment: No server-side control in my case "If you control the server side, you can split the message into several requests, but this isn't always the case."  Mango will make me feel happier as a developer, but it won't be until towards the end of the year that users will be able to use it ... I'm not sure that I want to descend into this world of pain - hopefully someone else has already been there :-)